# C++ 2D vector SIGSEV error

Tags: c++, vector, segmentation-fault

I am getting segmentation error in the following code, can anyone bother to explain. I think it might have to do with initialization, but not sure. I am just trying to clone the existing stack and perform operation such as adding entry to the clone or removing entry from existing and cloning it to new stack.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <vector>
#include <queue>
#include <deque>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

#define in cin
#define out cout

int main()
{
    //ifstream in("postfix.in");
    //ofstream out("postfix.out");

    int n;
    in>>n;

    long sum=0;
    vector<int> tm(0);
    vector<vector<int>> ar(0,tm);
    //ar[0].push_back(0);
    out<<ar[0][0];
    for(int i=0;i<n;i++)
    {
        int ind,val;
        in>>ind>>val;
        if(val==0)
        {
            for(int j=0;j<ar[ind-1].size();j++)
            ar[i].push_back(ar[ind-1][j]);
            ar[i].pop_back();
        }
        else
        {
            for(int j=0;j<ar[ind-1].size();j++)
            ar[i].push_back(ar[ind-1][j]);
            ar[i].push_back(val);
        }

    }

    for(int i=0;i<n;i++)
    {
        for(int j=0;j<ar[i].size();j++)
        sum+=ar[i][j];
    }

    out<<sum<<endl;

    return 0;

}
```

Comment: Have you debugged it?

Comment: `#define in cin #define out cout` -- Please stop doing this.  This just adds confusion to someone reading the code -- every C++ programmer knows what `cin` and `cout` are without them being hidden by a `#define` macro.

Comment: I am using #define statement cause i have to test it in console before using it with file stream it's just for convenience, and I just pasted the original code here, sorry for that.

Comment: @Carcigenicate I am working with gnu g++ which doesn't have any debugging tools.

Comment: @shubhamrock828 You dont need a debugger to debug. You could place print statements to isolate the problem then print out key parts of the code to analyze.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I see where you're getting tripped up.

```
vector<int> tm(0);
```

This does **not** create a vector containing a 0. This creates a vector with a size of 0. Because this list has a size of 0, you can't get the first element; since it's empty!

Same here:

```
vector<vector<int>> ar(0,tm);
```

This doesn't create a vector with 1 "row". It creates an empty vector, since you made the size 0 again.

You likely intended something like:

```
vector<int> tm(1, 0);
vector<vector<int>> ar(1,tm);
```

Which creates a row, `tm`, with a single 0, then creates a 2D vector, `ar` containing that 1 row.

Check the [reference](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/vector/vector/vector/). You're attempting to use the "fill" constructor.

Comment: Yes i figured that out... I misunderstood the reference from http://www.cplusplus.com/forum/beginner/12409/

Comment: @shubhamrock828 Ahh. Well glad you got it worked out.

Comment: Thanks @Carcigenicate,
do you think you can help me with finding time complexity for this question:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40578849/time-complexity-with-insertion-sort-for-2n-array

Answer (score 1):

```
vector<int> tm(0);
vector<vector<int>> ar(0,tm);
```

Here you initialized `ar` as an *empty* vector of vector of int. Without enlarging its size through `push_back()`, `resize()`, `insert()`, etc., you cannot access `ar[i]`.

You may instead initialize `ar` as

```
vector<vector<int>> ar(n);
```

But in the existing snippet you provided there is no clue about how large the second dimension should be.

Per your comment in this answer, your declaration of `tm` and `ar` should be

```
vector<int> tm(1, 0);
vector<vector<int>> ar(1, tm);
```

Or even shorter since `tm` is not really used later,

```
vector<vector<int>> ar(1, vector<int>(1, 0));
```

Comment: Thanks timaru, but i didn't get you here. What do you mean initialized empty vector? 
here i am trying to initialize the array at 0th index with tm vector. The tm vector is also initialized with one element that is '0'.

Answer (score 0):

For starters it is a bad idea to use such definitions

```
#define in cin
#define out cout
```

It is better to use explicitly `std::cin` and `std::cout` because any programmer knows what these names mean.

These declarations

```
vector<int> tm(0);
vector<vector<int>> ar(0,tm);
```

do not make great sense. It would be much clear and simpler just to write

```
vector<int> tm;
vector<vector<int>> ar;
```

SO as the vectors are empty you may not use the subscript operator as you are doing for instance here

```
out<<ar[0][0];
     ^^^^^^^^^
for(int i=0;i<n;i++)
{
    int ind,val;
    in>>ind>>val;
    if(val==0)
    {
        for(int j=0;j<ar[ind-1].size();j++)
                    ^^^^^^^^^^^ 
        ar[i].push_back(ar[ind-1][j]);
        ^^^^^
        ar[i].pop_back();
        ^^^^^
    }
```

and so on. You need at first ro append new elements to the vector before using the subscript operator.

Comment: I am using #define statement cause i have to test it in console before using it with file stream it's just for convenience, and I just pasted the original code here, sorry for that.

Further I am using: tm(0) and ar(0,tm) for initialization purpose, I don't see what is wrong here. and why wouldn't I get the 0 in output when i cout<<ar[0][0];

Comment: @shubhamrock828 Been awhile since I've used a vector, but iirc, giving the constructor a number specifies the size you want it to be. You said you want the size to be 0, so there is no 0th element of the vector to get, or, phrased another way, you can't get the first element of an empty vector.