# Time complexity with insertion sort for 2^N array?

Tags: sorting, time-complexity

Consider an array of integers, which has a size of 2^N, where the element at index X (0 ≤ X < 2N) is X xor 3 (that is, two least significant bits of X are flipped). What is the running time of the insertion sort on this array?

Comment: I don't understand why did someone down voted this question. I did surf for it's solution couldn't find any, thus i thought i should ask here in community.

Comment: You were likely downvoted since this is extremely easy to lookup. Googling "insertion sort time complexity" gave http://bigocheatsheet.com/ as the second result.

Answer (score 1):

Examine the structure of what the lists looks like:

For n = 2:

{3, 2, 1, 0}

For n = 3 :

{3, 2, 1, 0, 7, 6, 5, 4}

For insertion sort, you're maintaining the invariant that the list from 1 up to your current index is sorted, so you're task at each step is to place the current element into it's correct place among the sorted elements before it. In the worst case, you will have to traverse all previous indices before you can insert the current value (think of the case where the list is in reverse sorted order). But it's clear from the structure above that for a list with the property that each value is equivalent to the index ^ 3, that the furthest back in the list that you would have to go from any given index is 3. So you've reduced the possibility that you'd have to do O(n) work at the insertion step to a constant factor. But you still have to do O(n) work to examine each element of the list. So, for this particular case, the running time of insertion sort is linear in the size of the input, whereas in the worst case it is quadratic.